# Mark Favourites

Tags: feature-request

I think this is a feature request.

I know it's possible to mark a question as a favourite by clicking the star icon.

However is it possible to mark an answer as a favourite? There are some greta answers on the site that I would like to keep for future reference. I realise I can save or bookmark the link in my browser however this seems overly complicated!

It's possible that I am missing something here, apologies if so.

Comment: I think this is something that should be posted on [Meta StackExchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com), rather than here, as it's an all round feature request.